# Docker Swarm wait before sending traffic to a container

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

Let's say I have 1 stack with 3 services each running in my Docker Swarm. When I update a service, Docker creates new containers and deletes the old ones.
When a new container is created Docker automatically sends web traffic to the container even if it's not ready yet.

Is there a possibility to block traffic until the container is fully operational? like wait before entrypoint is finished otherwise, data will be sent to a container that can't handle it yet and will result in errors.

Comment: You want a healthcheck.

Comment: Thanks, I am going to try that!